# Clear drop-down history of Firefox

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, firefox, ubuntu-10.10, privacy

1. I was wondering how to clear the
   following privacy in Firefox 3.6.16:

   - when typing address in the address
     bar, the history meeting the partial
     typing provided by auto-completion.
   - without doing anything, the drop-down list of addresses in
     address bar

   Is it possible to just clear the
   former without clearing the latter, and without actually clearing the history i.e. you can still get the history by clicking `History->Show All History`?
2. What is the general strategy of
   protecting one's own privacy,  while
   keeping the history as much as
   possible?  My case is using Firefox
   on my personal laptop, which will
   occasionally be used by others under
   my account, for example, to help me
   solve some problems by typing some webpage address and visiting them in Firefox.

Operating systems are Windows 7 & Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Preferences, on the **Privacy** tab, there is a settings called **When using the location bar, suggest:**. Setting it to **Nothing** appears to affect both actions you mentioned: auto-complete while typing, and click the drop-down arrow. I don't think those two can be separated.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if there is some shortcut keys for switching between `Nothing` and `History and Bookmarks` for `When using the location bar, suggest`?