# Is it possible to create shortcut keys for changing preferences in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I asked a question in [my previous post](https://superuser.com/questions/268470/clear-drop-down-history-of-firefox), about how to hide drop-down history of Firefox 3.6.16 address bar. The solution is

> In Preferences, on the **Privacy**
>   tab, there is a settings called **When
>   using the location bar, suggest:**.
>   Setting it to **Nothing** appears to
>   affect both actions you mentioned:
>   auto-complete while typing, and click
>   the drop-down arrow.

I was wondering if there are some shortcut keys to switch between **Nothing** and **History and Bookmarks**?

If no, is it possible to customize as such?

Comment: I have been trying for a while to figure out which entry in `about:config` this setting changes. You wouldn't happen to know, would you? EDIT: Found it. For future reference, `browser.urlbar.autocomplete.enabled`.

Comment: @William: Thanks for still trying. Sorry, I don't know yet.

Comment: @William: have you also found a way to bind the switching to some key?

Comment: No, I have not found a way (natively or with an extension) to make a keyboard shortcut change an arbitrary preference.